# how to check array index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code in jquery

```
var newFeeds = [];
$(data.d).each(function () {
  newFeeds.push({
    content: this.Name,                               
    id: this.Id
  });        
});
```

I am able to access values from `newFeeds[0].content, newFeeds[1].content, newFeeds[2].content` but when I tried to 
 access `newFeeds[3].content` its showing undefined error and checked `typeof equals(===) undefined` but its showing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined` error. How can I avoid this error. I have only 3 elements in the array. Is there a way in Jquery to avoid this error or Can I set value not available in non existence index ?

Comment: `I have only 3 elements `, Then how can you read `newFeeds[3]`?

Comment: if(typeof newFeeds[i] !== undefined ) {do some}

Comment: I understand this but any method to check its not defined.

Comment: what comes in data.d ....

Comment: if (typeof variable === 'undefined' || !variable) { /* do things */ }; this works for me

Comment: jQuery.type(val) === "undefined" may help

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var newFeeds = [];
$(data.d).each(function (val) {
    if(val !== undefined) {
        newFeeds.push({
            content: val,
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 i=0
 while(i <= newsFeed.length)
   if (newFeeds[i])
      //Your code goes here
   else
      i++
```

Try by doing above.

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to access values from newFeeds[0].content,
>   newFeeds[1].content, newFeeds[2].content but when I tried to access
>   newFeeds[3].content its showing undefined error and checked typeof
>   equals(===) undefined but its showing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'content' of undefined error. How can I avoid this error. I
>   have only 3 elements in the array. Is there a way in Jquery to avoid
>   this error or Can I set value not available in non existence index ?

Use `(index_key in your_array)` Here is example

Checking for undefined-ness is not an accurate way of testing whether a key exists. What if the key exists but the value is actually undefined ?

```
"key" in your_object_or_array // true, regardless of the actual value
```

```js
var newfeeds = [{
  content: 'first'
}, {
  content: 'second'
}, {
  content: 'third'
}];

console.log(
   0 in newfeeds
);
console.log(
   2 in newfeeds
);
console.log(
   3 in newfeeds
);

/* So what you can use is */
var index_key = 1;
if(index_key in newfeeds){
    console.log(newfeeds[index_key].content);
}else{
   console.log(index_key + ' no such index');
}

var index_key = 3;
if(index_key in newfeeds){
    console.log(newfeeds[index_key].content);
}else{
   console.log(index_key + ' no such index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this way

```
 for (i = 0; i < 14;i++)
     {
        if (typeof newFeeds[i] !== undefined)
              {
                newFeeds.push({
                content: 'NA',
                id: 0
                             });

                 }

      }
```